# Wrong Image Resolution When Image is Picked with UIImagePickerController

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, resolution

I am using UIImagePickerController to access images from Camera Roll. The images were captured with default Camera app of iPhone.

On my side, I am using iPhone 4 and the captured images show full resolution of `2592x1936` pixels, both in my app as well as on the Preview program that runs on my MacBook.

When my client tests the app on his iPhone 5s, my app displays a resolution of `2048x1536` but the same image, when opened with Preview, shows a resolution of `3264x2448`.

I have transferred his image to Camera Roll of my iPhone 4 and the problem persists. My app still shows a lower resolution and the Preview shows full resolution.

I have also downloaded a huge image from wikipedia commons, with a resolution of `4288x2844`, and placed it on Camera Roll of my iPhone 4, to see if problem is due to large image sizes. This image, when loaded in my app, reports correct resolution.

I have checked `scale` property of `UIImage` and that is `1.0` for all situations. Below is the code that I use to access the images.

Please help me figure out why my code is reporting a scaled down resolution by a factor of `1.59375` for images captured on iPhone 5s using default Camera app.

```
- (IBAction)processLoadButton:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSLog(@"Image Resolution is %f x %f and scale is %f",originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height, originalImage.scale);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];   
}
```

Comment: Dude, did you find any answer?

Comment: No. I have not figured out how to access full-resolution images. Most probably, one has to use an approach different from the usual `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: I guess, if you upload image to your iPhone via iTunes from Mac it was "optimized" by resizing. I don't have other explanations :)